# read input & save in shared memory in Socket in C

Tags: c, sockets, ipc

I work on the server side Socket  (use Telnet client) in Linux. Client input a line with command(GET/PUT/DEL, key and an associated value (spaces to seperate in between). This key-value pair is then passed accordingly on to the function(GET/PUT/DEL), which saves the data in the shared memory (keyValueStore).

Expected client side: (> is the output from Server)

```
GET key1
    > GET:key1:key_nonexistent 
PUT key1 value1
    > PUT:key1:value1 
PUT key2 value2
    > PUT:key2:value2 
DEL key2
    > DEL:key2:key_deleted
```

Questions:

1/ i tried to use strtok() and keyValueStore to seperate & save the tokens in a normal c file, but how should I do (or transform) it into the data transfer communication between server and client?

2/ when or where should I call the command functions (e.g. int put(char* key, char* value) )? in server.c after reading the input but before giving output?

Any advices is appreicated. Thanks for your kindness!

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024 // Buffer Size
#define TRUE 1
#define PORT 5678

int main() {

    int rfd; // Create-Descriptor 
    int cfd; // Connection-Descriptor (accept)

    struct sockaddr_in client;
    socklen_t client_len;
    char in[BUFSIZE]; 
    int bytes_read; 

    // 1. socket() 
    rfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (rfd < 0 ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

 
    //Initialize the server address by the port and IP
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    memset(&server, '\0', sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET; // Internet address family: v4 address
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // Server IP address
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT); // Server port

    // 2. bind() 
    int brt = bind(rfd, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server));
    if (brt < 0 ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // 3. listen() = listen for connections
    int lrt = listen(rfd, 5);
    if (lrt < 0 ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    while (1) {

        // 4. accept() 
        cfd = accept(rfd, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &client_len);
 
        // read() = read from a socket (Client's data)
        bytes_read = read(cfd, in, BUFSIZE);

        while (bytes_read > 0) {
            printf("sending back the %d bytes I received...\n", bytes_read);
            // write() = write data on a socket (Client's data)
            write(cfd, in, bytes_read);
            bytes_read = read(cfd, in, BUFSIZE);
        }

        close(cfd);
    }
    close(rfd);
}
```

Input.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_ARRAY 100

int main() {

    typedef struct Value_ {
        char key[MAX_ARRAY];
        char value[MAX_ARRAY];
    } KeyStorage;
    KeyStorage storageKey[MAX_ARRAY];

    char client_input[MAX_ARRAY];
    char *argv[3];
    char *token;
    int count = 0;
    while (1) {
        printf("Input: ");
        gets(client_input);

//get the first token
        token = strtok(client_input, " ");
        int i = 0;
//walk through other tokens
        while (token != NULL) {
            argv[i] = token;
            i++;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        argv[i] = NULL; //argv ends with NULL

        // arg[0] = command z.B. GET, PUT
        printf("Commend: %s\n", argv[0]);

        strcpy(storageKey[count].key, argv[1]);
        printf("Key: %s\n", storageKey[count].key);

        strcpy(storageKey[count].value, argv[2]);
        printf("Value: %s\n", storageKey[count].value);

        count++;

        if (strcmp(argv[0], "QUIT") == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of errors in your code. I have fixed all to build a working example. Of course, this is not your complete application and there is even a lot of room for enhancements.

I developed and tested my code with MSVC2019 under Windows but I used a #define to isolate Windows specific code so it should compile and run correctly under Linux as well (I have not tested that).

The main problem your code had is a misunderstanding of TCP connection. It is a stream oriented connection and you must assemble "command lines" yourself, receiving one character at a time.

It is only when a line is complete that you can parse it to detect the command sent by the client. I made simple: only one command "exit" does something (close the connection). Everything else is simply ignored.

I made line assembling the easy way. That means that there is no edit possible. Backspace, delete, cursor keys and more and input as any other characters and doesn't work a a user would expect. You should take care of that.

Finally, I kept the code close to what you used. This code is *single user*. It accept a connection, accept commands from it and only accept a new connection once the first is closed. This is not normally the way to create a server program. To make it *multiuser*, you should use non-blocking socket and `select()` or use multi-threading.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #ifdef WIN32
    #include <WinSock2.h>
    #include <io.h>
    typedef int socklen_t;
    #pragma warning(disable : 4996)  // No warning for deprecated function names such as read() and write()
    #else
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #define closesocket close
    #endif
    
    #define BUFSIZE 1024 // Buffer Size
    #define TRUE 1
    #define PORT 5678
    
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    #ifdef WIN32
        int iResult;
        WSADATA wsaData;
    
        // Initialize Winsock
        iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
        if (iResult != 0) {
            printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
            return 1;
        }
    #endif
    
        int rfd; // Create-Descriptor 
        int cfd; // Connection-Descriptor (accept)
    
        struct sockaddr_in client;
        socklen_t client_len;
        char in[BUFSIZE];
        int bytes_read;
    
        // 1. socket() 
        rfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (rfd < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    
        // Initialize the server address by the port and IP
        struct sockaddr_in server;
        memset(&server, '\0', sizeof(server));
        server.sin_family = AF_INET; // Internet address family: v4 address
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // Server IP address
        server.sin_port = htons(PORT); // Server port
    
        // 2. bind() 
        int brt = bind(rfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server));
        if (brt < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    
        // 3. listen() = listen for connections
        int lrt = listen(rfd, 5);
        if (lrt < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    
        while (1) {
            client_len = sizeof(client);
            cfd = accept(rfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &client_len);
            if (cfd < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "accept failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                exit(-1);
            }
            printf("Client connected\n");
    
            while (1) {
/*
                // Send prompt to client
                char* prompt = "> ";
                if (send(cfd, prompt, strlen(prompt), 0) <= 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "send() failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                    exit(1);
                }
*/    
                // read a line from a socket (Client's data)
                int bytes_idx = -1;
                while (1) {
                    if (bytes_idx >= (int)sizeof(in)) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "input buffer overflow\n");
                        break;
                    }
                    // Receive on byte (character) at a time
                    bytes_read = recv(cfd, &in[++bytes_idx], 1, 0);
                    if (bytes_read <= 0)  // Check error or no data read
                        break;
    /*
                    printf("sending back the %d bytes I received...\n", bytes_read);
                    if (send(cfd, &in[bytes_idx], 1, 0) <= 0) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "send() failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                        exit(1);
                    }
    */
                    if (in[bytes_idx] == '\n') {
                        // Received a complete line, including CRLF
                        // Remove ending CR
                        bytes_idx--;
                        if ((bytes_idx >= 0) && (in[bytes_idx] == '\r'))
                            in[bytes_idx] = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (bytes_idx > 0) {   // Check for empty line
                    printf("Received \"%s\"\n", in);
                    // Check for client command
                    if (stricmp(in, "exit") == 0)
                        break;
                    else {
                        printf("Client sent unknown command\n");
                    }
                }
            }
            closesocket(cfd);
            printf("Client disconnected\n");
        }
        closesocket(rfd);
    
    #ifdef WIN32
        WSACleanup();
    #endif
    }
```

Comment: after runnning your code, it appears  ">"loop rather than what i want. But I am still grateful about your explanation of TCP connection and the effort in writing the code & comments which helps me to learn & have a direction. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want any prompt, then you can remove the lines that send it! Or send whatever prompt you like. Do you see how to do it?

Comment: after (1) removed ">"loop lines, there are (2) "input buffer overflow" loops. when i removed both and input "GET key1 hi", Received message did appear, but (3)"Client sent unknown command" also appeared which is incorrect. is it possible that i mark it as accepted, after u modify these points in the code? so that it helps other readers in the future, thanks for the effort.

Comment: You are right. Commented out lines for prompt, fixed bytes_idx bug (cast to compare with sizeof(in) and reset to -1 at the end of loop. Tell me if it works for you now.

Comment: 1/ byte(s)_idx = -1 , 2/ "Client sent unknown command" still appears . I have learnt from your code and comments, thanks for the patience.

Comment: *Client sent unknown command* Of course, I have implemented only one single command named "exit". Look at the line `if (stricmp(in, "exit") == 0)` and add as many `else if` as you need for other command. `stricmp` is probably to simple for you. You have to parse the string for an *opcode* and for *arguments* and then call the appropriate function to do the actual implementation. Ask another question if you don't know how to parse a string...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234164/discussion-between-user12595983-and-fpiette).