# Data Transfer b/w Server/Client in C

Tags: c, sockets, ipc

I work on the server side Socket (use Telnet client) in Linux. Client is required to input a line in certain format: command(GET/PUT/DEL) key and an associated value (spaces to seperate in between). This key-value pair is later passed accordingly to the function(GET/PUT/DEL), which saves the data in the shared memory (keyValueStore).

Before I try to spilt the input into 3 parts, I find two problems

1/ bytes_index is not what I expected(in yellow)

2/ Server doesn't show following lines (inside if (bytes_index > 0) )

e.g. Get key1 hi

```
printf("%s\n", input[0]); //G
printf("%s\n", input[1]); //e
printf("%s\n", input[2]); //t
```

-may I know the reason and if possible, any tips on how to solve them? Thanks!

[image]

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024 // Buffer Size
#define TRUE 1
#define PORT 5678

int main() {

    int rfd; // Create-Descriptor 
    int cfd; // Connection-Descriptor (accept)

    struct sockaddr_in client;
    socklen_t client_len;
    char input[BUFSIZE]; 
    int bytes_read; 

    // 1. socket() 
    rfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (rfd < 0 ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

 
    //Initialize the server address by the port and IP
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    memset(&server, '\0', sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET; // Internet address family: v4 address
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // Server IP address
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT); // Server port

    // 2. bind() 
    int brt = bind(rfd, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server));
    if (brt < 0 ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // 3. listen() = listen for connections
    int lrt = listen(rfd, 5);
    if (lrt < 0 ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    while (1) {

        // 4. accept() = accept a new connection on socket from client
        cfd = accept(rfd, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &client_len);
        if (cfd < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "accept failed with error %d\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        printf("Client connected\n");

        while (1) {

            int bytes_index = -1;
            while (1) {
                 bytes_read = recv(cfd, &input[++bytes_index], 1, 0);
                if (bytes_read <= 0)  // Check error or no data read
                    break;

                if (input[bytes_index] == '\n') {
                    // Received a complete line, including CRLF
                    // Remove ending CR
                    bytes_index--;
                    if ((bytes_index >= 0) && (input[bytes_index] == '\r'))
                        input[bytes_index] = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (bytes_index > 0) {   // Check for empty line
                printf("%s\n", input);
                printf("bytes_index: %d\n", bytes_index);
                printf("%s\n", input[0]);
                printf("%s\n", input[1]);
                printf("%s\n", input[2]);
                // Check for client command
                if (strcmp(input, "QUIT") == 0)
                    break;
            }
        }
        close(cfd);
        printf("Client disconnected\n");
    }
    close(rfd);
}
```

Comment: "*bytes_index is not what I expected*". So what do you expect it to be and why? Don't expect people to know what you mean by "not expected".

Comment: `recv(cfd, &input[++bytes_index]` and `printf("%s\n", input[0]);` They can't work. `input[X]` is a single `char` not a character buffer as required.

Comment: updated, sorry and thanks for the reminder.

Comment: `printf("%s\n", input[0])` needs to be `printf("%c\n", input[0])` to print a single character.

Comment: @kaylum `recv(cfd, &input[++bytes_index], 1, 0);` works well enough on its own as `&input[++bytes_index]` is the address of a `char`, but there are problems with the rest of the code.  The data read never gets properly terminated so it can't be treated as a string, and any array bounds checking is lacking.

Comment: @AndrewHenle True, I misspoke for the recv as missed the fact that it was 1 byte at a time. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @kaylum a silly mistake, thanks!

Comment: It looks like you are using a modified version of my code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68100587/189103) but you did not clearly understood how it works. Revert back to what I wrote, try to understand it fully and only then - as I said in the related question - implement the commands you want, replacing the code after `// Check for client command`.

Comment: In my [original code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68100587/189103), the data was properly null terminated but you removed that part of the code!